# Uninitialized Value Error when using AdamOptimizer

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gradient

I was trying to construct a minimalistic gradient computation example in Tensorflow. However I always get a **FailedPreconditionError** error. Here is what I am doing:

```
sess = tf.Session()  
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="x1")  
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="x2")  
grad_a1_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1], name="grad_a1_ph")  
a1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]), name="a1")  
a2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]), name="a2")  
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  
adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
w = a1**2*x1**2 + a2**2*x2**2
```

So I am trying to just minimize the function w(x1, x2) which is just a quadratic function in a1, a2, x1, and x2, therefore i.e. a1=0 should give the minimum.

```
grad_a1 = adam.compute_gradients(loss=w, var_list=[a1])
```

I can compute dw/da1 at x1 = 2, x2 = 1

```
x1_np = 2 * np.ones([1]).reshape(1, 1)
x2_np = 1 * np.ones([1]).reshape(1, 1)
grad_a1_buffer = sess.run(grad_a1, feed_dict={x1:x1_np, x2:x2_np})
```

And it gives the expected result 8.
Now I am trying to apply the gradient I just computed using the following code:

```
updateGrads = adam.apply_gradients(zip([grad_a1_ph],[a1]))
sess.run(updateGrads, feed_dict={grad_a1_ph:grad_a1_buffer[0][0]})
```

And I get the **FailedPreconditionError** on a1 on the line with sess.run():

```
ailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power
 [[Node: beta1_power/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@a1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](beta1_power)]]
```

The variable **a1** is definitely initialized because I don't have any problems to compute w or dw/da1 if I provide values for x1 and x2.
It would be a big help if somebody points out what could be wrong with my example.

Many thanks in advance
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

**after** (not before)

```
adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
```

or any other operation that creates variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed I needed to define all operations before I call sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())